# Wake up QThread::exec() from another thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread, qtcore

Consider *MyThread* that derives from [QThread](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qthread.html) and implements it's run() routine like this

```
void MyThread::run() {
  QThread::exec();
}
```

or equivalently

```
void MyThread::run() {
  QEventLoop eventLoop(this);
  eventLoop.exec();
}
```

In this state how does one cause the 'exec' to return by some action in *another* thread?

To consider the opposite case: without polling, how might one post an event from the thread back to the main thread?

Apparently signals that are emitted from a thread are handled in the same thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have some misunderstanding how QThreads are supposed to work. Unfortunately, you are not alone with this.

The first thing to do is to read about the correct usage in here:

[How To Really, Truly Use QThreads; The Full Explanation](http://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/)

So, what you should write is something like this:

```
QThread* thread1 = new QThread;
QThread* thread2 = new QThread;
Task1* task1 = new Task1();
task1->moveToThread(thread1);
Task2* task2 = new Task2();
task2->moveToThread(thread2);
connect(task2, SIGNAL(finished()), thread1, SLOT(quit()));
connect(thread2, SIGNAL(started()), task2, SLOT(process()));
thread1->start();
thread2->start();
```

As you can see, I am using the quit() slot just like the aforementioned example. You will need to use then `emit finished()` in your task2 which tries to terminate thread1 or vice versa.

Comment: Why is it that everyone on this site tries to spread their ideas of "The right way"TM instead of actually answering the question? Is programming, there is often no correct answer as there are multiple ways of dealing with problems. Even though solutions like this are probably what you want to use if you were building something for nasa, it might not be the right solution if you want to just hack something together in five minutes and then never look at it again. In sum, yes, provide your link on "the right way" in case that it is relevant to him, but also answer the question that was asked.

Comment: With this model is it possible to emit events from the *thread* and have them handled in my main thread?

Comment: @TruthSerum: sure, see this connection in the example, `connect(worker, SIGNAL(error(QString)), this, SLOT(errorString(QString)));`.

Comment: @chacham15: you do realize I made the right way in less than two minutes?

Comment: @FinalContest the code itself may be short, but the understanding of what is going on takes much longer. Furthermore, it is only short because you assume that the structure of the program has these worker objects.

Comment: @chacham15: I fail to see why. It is straight-forward to many, including me, how it was designed and yes, I prefer to use the right solution when helping newcomers raher than growing the mess. ;-) I am sorry to hear that you are unhappy to follow the usage how the class was meant.

Comment: @TruthSerum: you need your task/worker object. Again, see the example in the link.

Comment: @TruthSerum: further reading material on the topic, http://blog.debao.me/2013/08/how-to-use-qthread-in-the-right-way-part-1/ Please follow the links in that posts, too.

Answer (score 1):

QEventLoop has a slot `quit` that you can call. If you put a reference to the eventloop in your mythread, you can then use that to call the slot.

Signals/slots can be used in a cross thread fashion. More information here: [Signals and Slots Across Threads](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads-qobject.html#signals-and-slots-across-threads)

`QMetaObject::invokeMethod( eventloop, "quit", Qt::QueuedConnection)`

Comment: I have tested this. By printing QThread::currentThreadId() I can see that the thread that emits the signal is also the thread that handles the signal. This answer does not help me. The API should use the QThread::currentThreadId() during connect() and emit() to decide where the event should be posted, but it appears that it does not.

Comment: That is false, it depends on the situation. From the documentation itself: `If the signal is emitted in the thread which the receiving object has affinity then the behavior is the same as the Direct Connection. Otherwise, the behavior is the same as the Queued Connection.` Queued connection: `The slot is invoked when control returns to the event loop of the receiver's thread. The slot is executed in the receiver's thread.` Please read the link I provided.

Comment: EMIT EXECUTE FROM THREAD: 0x7f86dd5dc780
HANDLE EXECUTE FROM THREAD: 0x7f86dd5dc780

Comment: There is something wrong with your test code. Theres nothing more for me to say.

Comment: I think it's because I connect(this,SIGNAL,this,SLOT) and this==this. But where is it documented that it is these pointers that govern how the messages is transferred?

Comment: @TruthSerum yes, `this` can only belong to one thread so it will be handled in the same thread.